# Evitando dump para usuários do MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, dump

Para um usuário específico do MySQL, existe como bloquear para que o ele não faça o Data Export (DUMP) de uma tabela específica, ou do banco inteiro?

Não encontrei uma solução...
Como vocês lidam com isto?

Obrigado!

Comment: Acredito que seja só questão do usuário não ter acesso à base de dados, isso? Porque nada impediria o usuário de fazer login no banco e fazer dump das tabelas, um a um.

Comment: Isso que o @RodrigoRigotti disse só o usuário não ter permissão de leitura da tabela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um usuário pode ser criado com permissão de leitura (`select`) especificamente para determinadas tabelas e isso não implica em dar acesso a base de dados inteira para ele.

Segundo [esta resposta](https://serverfault.com/a/22718) do Server Fault, para realizar o *dump* ele também precisaria de pelo menos a permissão `lock tables`.

Entretanto, ao dar permissão de leitura para tabelas específicas, não fique preocupado se o usuário pode fazer o *dump* dessas tabelas, afinal ele pode simplesmente executar um `select` na tabela inteira e salvar os resultados sem dificuldades.